# How do websites track users by IP when most user use internet behind NAT?

Tags: ip, nat

On a home network, the IP address we get is private IP, and IP address returned by whatismyipaddress.com is IP address of the ISP. Our routers acts as a NAT device, and changes the network packet's source's/destination's IP addresses.

So, if the website like stackoverflow.com receives the IP address of our router, instead of our private IP, how does it track the users using IP addresses, and do stuff like IP ban?

Comment: Look up “ browser fingerprinting”. Some sites use tracking cookies as well

Answer (score 0):

> So, if the website like stackoverflow.com receives the IP address of our router, instead of our private IP, how does it track the users using IP addresses, and do stuff like IP ban?

In the most typical case (still), the ISP issues one IP address *per customer.* That address is directly assigned to your router, and if you get banned your whole household gets banned. (Or the whole office or business or library or whatever.) Although that's not always the case, many systems just assume that it still is and just whack whatever IP address they see.

Things get more complex when ISPs start moving customers behind CGNAT (which might not necessarily *share* an address between customers, but might be much more dynamic at reassigning them from one customer today to another tomorrow), or when you're dealing with inherently dynamic connections such as 3G/4G. I don't have an accurate answer about those (though I've heard once that some sites use databases to keep track of "known dynamic" address ranges where it's pointless to use IP bans so they simply *don't* do IP bans).

Sometimes the site may just ban the entire IP address block; e.g. with ISPS and especially VPN providers that ignore abuse reports, it's common for a site to look up *all* address ranges in use by the provider's AS (which is public information from routing registries) and block all of them at once.